# Installing Zend framework on a Unix web server

Tags: zend-framework, unix

I would like to install the Zend framework on a Unix server, but I can't find any good guides on the web for how to do so. I've looked at the guide at: http://akrabat.com/wp-content/uploads/Getting-Started-with-Zend-Framework.pdf but it doesn't have instructions for Unix. I'm not an expert with Unix but I know the basics of how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

As PHP is a portable language, installing Zend Framework on either Windows, Linux, Unix or any other should be exactly the same.

Simply ensure your library paths are setup correctly. I have a habit of forcing this in the index.php:

```
defined('PROJECT_PATH') || define('PROJECT_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../'));

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(PROJECT_PATH . '/library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));
```

Using this setup you may copy (or symlink) the [zf-1.x/library/Zend] directory into your [project/library/Zend] directory.

You can also add Zend Framework to a more standard location [Linux: /usr/share/php/Zend] and add this location to the php.ini include_path directive:

```
$ cat /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini | grep include_path
include_path = ".:/usr/share/php"
```

After setting your include_path either through code or the php.ini, simply require_once the main application class and setup an auto-loader for the rest of the application.

Other things to consider are:
* Installing PHP itself
* The interface to PHP (Apache2?) and configuring that appropriately

Best of luck!